# Parameter "StrongAssemblyName" must be specified if the flag "gacinstall" is used

Tags: windows, dll, registry, .net-assembly, compiler-warnings

While using Inno-Setup I included some DLLs in the [File] section and flagged them using "gacinstall", however on compile I get the error:

> Parameter "StrongAssemblyName" must be specified if the flag "gacinstall" is used.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after reading this [post](http://odd-staff.blogspot.com/2010/04/well.html), I modified my statement to:

```
Source: "C:\mfanimpelas\st_projects\RxPipelineSync\bin\RxPipelineSync\GAC\GAC\DevExpress.XtraReports.v12.1.Extensions.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; StrongAssemblyName: "MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=48d60606109a2257, ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL"; Flags: "gacinstall sharedfile uninsnosharedfileprompt"
```

Did this for EACH dll. I wonder if I cannot do a batch or read from file for the 101 list. But for now, this works.